# Related Docker networks for apps in separate Ansible roles

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible, reverse-proxy

Suppose I'm using a webserver / reverse proxy (traefik, nginx, apache, etc.) for various apps. If the webserver and all the apps are in the same `docker-compose.yml` then it's easy to configure the network, e.g.:

```yaml
networks:
  traefik-appfoo:
  traefik-appbar:

services

  traefik:
    # ...
    networks:
      - traefik-appfoo
      - traefik-appbar

  appfoo:
    # ...
    networks:
      - traefik-appfoo

  appbar:
    # ...
    networks:
      - traefik-appbar
```

But that is a simplistic deployment. In reality I have an an ansible playbook with multiple roles:

```
roles/
 traefik/   # installs and configures traefik
 appfoo/    # installs and configures foo, which is reverse-proxied by traefik
 appbar/    # installs and configures bar, which is reverse-proxied by traefik
 appbaz/    # ...
playbook.yml
```

Each role has its own `docker-compose.yml`. So I must somehow pass a network name from the app roles to the traefik role. The traefik role's `docker-compose.yml` would look like this:

```yaml
networks:
  ?                         # <----------
  ?                         # <----------

services
  traefik:
    # ...
    networks:
      - ?                   # <----------
      - ?                   # <----------
```

*I don't want to hardcode networks in the traefik role*: that is messy, hard to maintain, and roles would not be independent.

In the past when I did this, in each app role I had ansible fragments which were uploaded to some directory on the server, e.g. `traefik/docker-compose.yml.d/`. And every time I added a new app role, I'd have to run a task to [assemble](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assemble_module.html) the fragments into a complete `docker-compose.yml` for traefik. And if I had to run the original traefik role, it was idempotent as it would reassemble the fragments properly. This approach works, but the roles are not fully independent, and *it's very hard to maintain*.

Is there a simpler way to handle this scenario? The same problem would apply for any app with dependent apps (that are installed later, in separate roles).

Comment: Don't put all applications inside the same compose file. Make one independent compose file for each. Declare one single network for traefik, Use that network as en external network resource in other applications

Comment: @Zeitounator I do have separate compose files for each app. But sharing the same network with all apps would work, but it's not a good way to do it because you typically want to isolate all apps. It's certainly an option though.

Comment: I can see several ways to still acheive some degree of isolation even having a single reverse proxy network with e.g. frontends from each project participating in it while communicating with other application services on an other... but 1) it is a too wide subject to be discussed in comments 2) we are definitely crossing the off-topic line as this is more a network/system than a development issue. You might want to try https://superuser.com for that one.

Comment: @Zeitounator That's another interesting idea. I think the problem is when we try to isolate it fully we get other problems - "you can't have your cake and eat it" :-). I am using ansible fragments BTW, and it's messy but it gives you *almost* complete isolation.